# How to use iOS security scoped bookmarks across devices?

Tags: ios, uidocument, security-scoped-bookmarks

On iOS (14/15) I'm trying to pass security scoped bookmarks to user picked files on iCloud Drive between devices but whatever I try: I cannot get urls to be restored on another device running the same app.

The app is a UIDocument based app, the code below is in a UIViewController that display the document. The document is created like so:

```
Document* document = [[Document alloc] initWithFileURL:documentURL];
```

and then passed on to the ViewController

The url that's going to be bookmarked is picked using a plain UIDocumentPickerViewController

This is how I create a security scoped bookmark:

```
// Toggle this to create either a document scoped url or an app scoped url
static BOOL DOC_SCOPE = NO;

- (void) documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController*)controller didPickDocumentsAtURLs:(NSArray <NSURL *>*)urls {
    if (urls.count > 0) {
        NSURL* url = urls.firstObject;
        NSURL* docURL = self.document.fileURL;
        BOOL closeSource = [docURL startAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
        BOOL doClose = [url startAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
        NSData* bookmark = [url bookmarkDataWithOptions:0 includingResourceValuesForKeys:nil relativeToURL:DOC_SCOPE?docURL:nil error:nil];
        if (doClose)
            [url stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
        if (closeSource)
            [docURL stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
        NSString* encoded =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n[%@]\n", [bookmark base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];
```

At this point I insert the encoded bookmark data in the document data and save the document.

When opening the linked document the bookmark and url are restored like so:

```
openLink:(NSString*)encoded {
    NSData* bookmark = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:encoded options:0];
    NSURL* docURL = self.document.fileURL;
    BOOL closeSource = [docURL startAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData:bookmark options:0 relativeToURL:DOC_SCOPE?docURL:nil bookmarkDataIsStale:nil error:&error];
    if (error != nil)
        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedFailureReason);
    if (url != nil) {
        BOOL doClose = [url startAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
        // here use the url to access linked file
        if (doClose)
            [url stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
    }
    if (closeSource)
        [docURL stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
}
```

To the project's entitlements I have added

```
com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope = 1
com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.document-scope = 1
```

When on the same device I can the restore the bookmark data and get access to the restored URL OK, but when opening the same file on another device, [NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData...] always sets an error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."
```

This is both the case for app scope book marks and document scope book marks.

Any idea what's missing / how to get this working?